# Retrieve all data from firebase where users' posts are in uid

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have an android app where users submit their posts and only them can view what they posted. I achieved that using the code below

```
 String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
    mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("reports").child(uid);
```

However I have a separate admin app where i want to see what all the users post but i cant be able to achieve that. Please help

below is an image of my database
[image: Database image]

Comment: mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("reports"); if you add .(UID) it means it only retrieves the single entry.

Comment: I have tried this but it brings empty spaces without content

Comment: natumaini jibu langu la pili linafaa

Comment: From what i'm seeing in your database structure, under the `reports` node, some children are stored with the `pushId` as the parent key, and some (e.g the 4th child of `reports`) are stored with the user's unique id. That being said, what part of your database node contains all what you want your admin to see and what part of your datatabase node contains the actual user posts? The ones with the user's unique id as the parent or the ones with the firebase push id as the parent or both?

Comment: I want the users to only see what they have posted(  the 4th child of reports), and admin to view everything in the database ( the 4th child of reports) the first three are just demos which i should delete

Answer (score 0):

`mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("reports")` will get all reports for you.

Comment: I have tried this but it brings empty spaces without content

Answer (score 0):

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference reportsRef = rootRef.child("reports");
ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        List<String, Object> list = new ArrayList<>();
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String docId = ds.getKey();
            list.add(docId);
            Log.d("TAG", docId);
        }
        Log.d("TAG", list);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
reportsRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
```

Comment: It underlines the ds in bracket then dispalys this error: Wrong 2nd argument type. Found: 'com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot', required: 'java.lang.String' less...

Comment: It undelines the last list in the bracket

Comment: Error:(91, 30) error: incompatible types: List<String> cannot be converted to String

Comment: It still underlines the last list

Comment: oh its just an example because i dont know the data type of your data stored in the realtime database use data type any.

Comment: new to that language so just followed normal logic,

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code

```
public class MyReports extends Fragment {


private RecyclerView mBlogList;
private GridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager;
private DatabaseReference mDatabase;
private DatabaseReference mDatabaseUsers;

private DatabaseReference mDatabaseLike;

private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthListner;

private boolean mProcessLike = false;


public MyReports() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_my_reports, container, false);

    mAuth =FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    mAuthListner = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {

            if(firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser() == null){

                Intent loginIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), Login.class);
                loginIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(loginIntent);

            }

        }
    };

    mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("reports");
    mDatabaseUsers = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");
    mDatabaseLike =FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Likes");

    mDatabase.keepSynced(true);
    mDatabaseUsers.keepSynced(true);
    mDatabaseLike.keepSynced(true);

    mBlogList = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.blog_list);
    mBlogList.setHasFixedSize(true);
    mBlogList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));



    return view;

}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();


    FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Blog, BlogViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Blog, BlogViewHolder>(
            Blog.class,
            R.layout.post_row,
            MyReports.BlogViewHolder.class,
            mDatabase

    ) {
        @Override
        protected void populateViewHolder(MyReports.BlogViewHolder viewHolder, Blog model, final int position) {

            final String post_key =getRef(position).getKey();

            viewHolder.setOutreach(model.getOutreach());
            viewHolder.setDate(model.getDate());
            viewHolder.setNamee(model.getNamee());
            viewHolder.setPhone(model.getPhone());
            viewHolder.setPartici(model.getPartici());
            viewHolder.setLesson(model.getLesson());

            viewHolder.setImage(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),model.getImage());
            viewHolder.setImage1(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),model.getImage1());
            viewHolder.setImage2(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),model.getImage2());
            viewHolder.setImage3(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),model.getImage3());

            viewHolder.setImage4(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),model.getImage4());

            viewHolder.setLikeBtn(post_key);

            viewHolder.mView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {

                    //Toast.makeText(getActivity(), post_key, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    Intent singleBlogIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), PostSingleActivity.class);
                    singleBlogIntent.putExtra("blog_id", post_key);
                    startActivity(singleBlogIntent);
                }
            });

            viewHolder.mLikebtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {

                    mProcessLike = true;

                    if(mProcessLike){

                        mDatabaseLike.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                                if(dataSnapshot.child(post_key).hasChild(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid())){

                                }else {
                                    mDatabaseLike.child(post_key).child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).setValue("RandomValue");
                                }
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                            }
                        });

                    }

                }
            });

        }
    };

    mBlogList.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);


}

public static class BlogViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    View mView;
    ImageButton mLikebtn;

    DatabaseReference mDatabaseLike;
    FirebaseAuth mAuth;


    public BlogViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        mView = itemView;
        mLikebtn = (ImageButton) mView.findViewById(R.id.like_btn);

        mDatabaseLike = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Likes");
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        mDatabaseLike.keepSynced(true);
    }

    public void setLikeBtn(final String post_key){

        mDatabaseLike.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                if(dataSnapshot.child(post_key).hasChild(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid())){

                    mLikebtn.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_new_like_blue);

                }else {

                    mLikebtn.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_new_like_red2);

                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

    }

    public void setOutreach(String title){
        TextView post_title = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.post_outreach);
        post_title.setText(title);
    }

    public void setDate(String desc){
        TextView post_desc = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.post_date);
        post_desc.setText(desc);
    }

    public void setNamee(String username){
        TextView post_username = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.post_namee);
        post_username.setText(username);
    }

    public void setPhone(String date){
        TextView post_date = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.post_phone);
        post_date.setText(date);
    }

    public void setPartici(String phone){
        TextView post_phone = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.post_partici);
        post_phone.setText(phone);
    }


    public void setLesson(String date){
        TextView post_date = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.post_lesson);
        post_date.setText(date);
    }


    public void setImage(Context ctx, String image){
        ImageView post_image = (ImageView) mView.findViewById(R.id.post_image);
        Picasso.with(ctx).load(image).into(post_image);
    }

    public void setImage1(Context ctx, String image1){
        ImageView post_image1 = (ImageView) mView.findViewById(R.id.post_image1);
        Picasso.with(ctx).load(image1).into(post_image1);
    }

    public void setImage2(Context ctx, String image2){
        ImageView post_image2 = (ImageView) mView.findViewById(R.id.post_image2);
        Picasso.with(ctx).load(image2).into(post_image2);
    }

    public void setImage3(Context ctx, String image3){
        ImageView post_image3 = (ImageView) mView.findViewById(R.id.post_image3);
        Picasso.with(ctx).load(image3).into(post_image3);
    }

    public void setImage4(Context ctx, String image4){
        ImageView post_image4 = (ImageView) mView.findViewById(R.id.post_image4);
        Picasso.with(ctx).load(image4).into(post_image4);
    }
}


public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();

    // Set title bar
    ((MainActivity) getActivity())
            .setActionBarTitle("Reports");

}
```

}

Comment: Please add your code to the question and not as an answer